# Finding coordinate in radius

Tags: mathematics, vector, linear-algebra

Hello i have two points (Vector3) `A` and `B`. And have a radius `r`

[image]

How can i find a coords of point `P` in a circle by angle?

Comment: add point you need to find and angle to picture

Comment: done. New point P on the picture with angle=130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for 2D vectors:

```
Vector2 AB = B - A;  // Vector from A to B

Vector2 A0 = r * AB.normalized;  // Vector from A to 0°
Vector2 A90 = new Vector2(A0.y, -A0.x);  // Vector from A to 90°

Vector2 P = A + Sin(alpha) * A90 + Cos(alpha) * A0;  // Coordinate of arbitrary point on a circle
```

For arbitrary 3D vectors A and B in 3D space you need coordinates of at least one more point on the same plane (but not located on the A-B line).